# Is SynchronousUpdating->False supposed to make this simple Dynamic example work?

Tags: dynamic, asynchronous-processing

```
x = 0; Dynamic[{x, Button["+1", Pause[6]; x++]}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

The documentation states that Dynamic and Manipulate will abort synchronous computations that take longer than 5 seconds. The stated solution to this is to set SynchronousUpdating to False. That does not seem to work here. If I pause for 5 or fewer seconds it always works, but if I pause for 6 or more seconds, x always stays at 0 no matter the setting for SynchronousUpdating.

Answer (score 3):

Eh, the answer lay a click deeper in the documentation. You need to set Method->"Queued" on Button, then you don't even need to disable SynchronousUpdating. This now works as expected.

```
x = 0; Dynamic[Button[x, Pause[6]; x++, Method -> "Queued"]]
```

Comment: +1 for self-answering and sharing the solution.